# vs code Invalid regular expression Lone Qualifier brackets

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

Okay, I can't figure this out.   I've got a JSON file that I'm trying to clean up.   There is a nested loop I want to remove.  That is, a snippet of the later file is

```
{"properties": 
   {
      "bob": "foo"
   },
   "geometry": {
      "cat": "dog",
      "coodinates": [
         -20,
         10
      ]
  }
}
```

I'm trying to remove the "geometry" portion, that is

```
   "geometry": {
      "cat": "dog",
      "coodinates": [
         -20,
         10
      ]
  }
```

so that the result is

```
{"properties": 
   {
      "bob": "foo"
   },
}
```

Fine, so I thought, why don't I use the Find/Replace function in VS Code.   Great, so I use regex101.com and come up with

```
(?<="geometry")((.|\n)*).}
```

But, when I plug this into VS Code's Find/Replace function - VS Code yells at me with:

```
vs code Invalid regular expression:  (?<="geometry")((.|\n)*).}: Lone Qualifier brackets
```

What is wrong?   Why can I run this rgex101.com and not VS Code?   Please help the clueless.

Comment: what if there is a sub object `{}` in the geometry, it fails, you have to count the open and close braces, not something you can do with regex, VSC has a command **Select to Bracket**

Comment: Use find: `,?\s*"geometry":[\s\n\S]*?\}` and replace with `$1` - as mentioned in the comments below.

Answer (score 0):

Certain characters have special meaning in regex and if you wish to use them literally then you must escape them, a quantifier bracket is something like `{3}`

The end of your regex has a lone quantifier bracket; it should be escaped:

```
(?<="geometry")((.|\n)*).\}
```

Comment: I wonder why that didn't happen when I rand it on the regex101.com ??

Comment: @HuckleberryCarignan regex is implementation specific meaning that each programming language or in this case, program, is free to implement whatever rules and error-checking they see fit. There are lots of different flavors and interoperability of regex is **never** guaranteed, albeit 90% of the syntax is cross-compatible. VS Code simply decided that lone quantifier brackets are not allowed.

Comment: Well, this is weird!  That slash made the error go away, but now the regex is not working the wey it worked in regex101.com - grrrrr!

Comment: Thanks @MonkeyZues, that explains it

Comment: @HuckleberryCarignan Well, you haven't shared your regex101 attempt so I can only guess but it's likely related to regex flag (modifiers) which you used on regex101  but not in VS Code. See https://regex101.com/r/xZmjAE/1 for my attempt at your issue.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Add a `\n` so it works in vscode: `,?\s*"geometry":[\s\n\S]*?\}`

Comment: @Mark I've never used VS Code. Does `\s` not account for newline chars?

Comment: @Mark `[\s\S]` is just a workaround for regex implementations which do not support the DOTALL modifier.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus No, it doesn't.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/60871#issuecomment-429934557 (and more in that issue) - took me awhile to find it.  It looks like for performance reasons, multiline mode is not triggered without an explicit `\n`.

Comment: @Mark Interesting, I never knew it relies on ripgrep! Actually, that likely explains why OP's lookbehind assertion is failing to work. "VS Code does support regular expression searches, however, **backreferences, lookaround, and multiline matches are not supported**. This is because VS Code depends on the search tool ripgrep, which, while extremely fast, doesn't support these advanced regex features." I guess Notepad++ just spoils me rotten =)

Comment: Vscode does support lookarounds now.  It differs some for global searches vs. local file searches.  Non-fixed-width lookbehinds are not supported in global searches but do work in a single file find/replace, for example.  And since he wants to remove the `geometry` object I assume he doesn't really want lookbehind anyway.

Comment: @Mark Per https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep, is that done via "opt-in support for PCRE2"?

Comment: No, that PCRE2 settings option is long-gone from vscode.